# How do I set a default Ruby version using RVM?

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-lion, rvm

I installed Ruby, Rails and other stuff from [rubyinstaller.org](http://rubyinstaller.org) on to my MacOS X Lion system. However, I am not able to override the Mac version of Ruby which is 1.8.3. How do I overrite it to the latest version? When I try to run the following command:

```
rvm use 1.9.3-p392
```

It says:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p392 is not installed.
```

Another issue is when I try to connect to MySQL using:

```
mysql -u root
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
```

Comment: Did you use rvm to install ruby-1.9.3-p392?

Comment: no I downloaded from <railsinstaller.org> website

Comment: Don't ask multiple questions, especially ones that aren't really related. It's not a matter of whether you want to open up multiple questions, it's whether the multiple questions can be answered clearly, which they can't be. In my opinion, this question should be closed and you should open one to deal with your Ruby installation issues, and, once that's fixed, deal with MySQL. Trying to do that in the opposite order won't work well because your MySQL access will have to be reestablished once you have Ruby working correctly.

Comment: Do NOT try to overwrite the Apple-installed version of Ruby. Instead, get RVM working, or, instead, remove RVM and use rbenv. In either case, you'll have access to more recent versions of Ruby, and the ability to easily switch between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install whichever version you like, for example `rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p392`. Then you can make this the default by using `rvm use --default ruby-1.9.3-p392`. You must `install` before you can `use`.

See the [**cheat sheet**](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rvm) for a brief overview or consult the comprehensive documentation indexed at the bottom of the page here: https://rvm.io/

Your second question regarding MySQL should be filed separately (chances are you haven't yet started the MySQL server).

Comment: Now i got rid of the

Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket 

error. I was basically trying to connect to sql from a different directory from where mysql is actually installed.